# Is the space of point measures closed?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $M_+ (E)$ be the space of positive Radon measures on a polish complete, separable metric space $E$ with associated Borel-field $\mathcal{E}$.
Let further be $ M_p(E)$ the space of point measures on E.
We define the vague convergence of measures on $E$ by:

$m_n \rightarrow m$ iff

$\forall f \in C_K^+(E)$ we have $\int_E f(x) m_n(dx) \rightarrow \int_E f(x) m(dx)$ where $C_K^+(E)$ is the space of positive, continous functions with compact support on $E$.

In his book Extreme Values, Regular Variation and Point Processes Resnick says that $M_p(E)$ is vaguely closed in $M_+(E)$.
Some pages later an exercice appears stating that 
$m _n =\sum_{i= 1}^n 1/n \times \delta_{i \over n}$ converges vaguely towards the Lebesgue measure on $[0, \infty]$.
What am I missing? The Lebesgue measure is clearly no point measure, but still the space of point measures is closed.
Does someone have an explanation? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: If "point measure" means "finite linear combination of point masses" then indeed this set is not vaguely closed.  So either the definition is not what you think it is, or else Resnick has made a mistake.  (By the way, in the exercise you mention, the limit should be Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, not $[0,\infty]$.)

Comment: @NateEldredge I consider $\sum_n2^{-n}\delta_{n}$ as a point measure, which is not a *finite* l.c. of point masses.

Comment: @amsmath: Okay. The space of countable linear combinations of point masses is not vaguely closed either.

Comment: @NateEldredge Well, obviously not, as the example shows. ;-)

Comment: Maybe your definition of a point measure is that all coefficients of diracs are either 0 or 1?

Comment: @PhoemueX you are right that's what I was missing out. There are no coefficients allowed in the Resnick's definition.